# Are these two statements true or false?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, cardinals

1. For all sets $A,B$ we have that $|A \cup B|=|A|+|B|$ whereby $|\text{ }|$ stands for the cardinality.
2. For all vectors $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ the vector $u= \left \langle v,w \right \rangle v \text{ } - \left\|v\right\|^{2}w$ is located vertically at $v$ whereby $\left \langle , \right \rangle$ stands for the euclidean scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

I think first statement is false because to be true it must be subtracted by $|A \cap B|$ and also this must be finite and it's not stated in the task either. Or that is wrong? I still say it's false because this is unclear from task still.

About the other statement I have no idea at all : /

Comment: you're right. $|A \cup B|$ is equal to $|A| + |B| - |A \cap B |$.

Comment: How is it possible that one knows about linear algebra (dot product, norm, vector etc.) but not about the formula $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$?

Comment: @Levent  The OP knows that fact and uses it in their post, to justify why they think $(1)$ is false.  Any way, please don't "do" sarcasm at the other party's expense.

Comment: @amWhy I was not sarcastic, I am sorry if I offended the OP. I was just trying to understand the context of these two problems.

Comment: Please do not ask two unrelated things in one question.

Comment: Ask only one question per question. And especially do not ever ask two unrelated things in one question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your reasoning for the first statement is completely correct.

For the second statement, I believe "located vertically at $v$" means "orthogonal to $v$." To prove that two vectors are orthogonal, take their dot product and show that it is $0$. In other words, show that:
$$\langle u, v \rangle=\langle \langle v, w \rangle v-\|v\|^2w, v\rangle$$
is equal to $0$. (Hint: Remember that $\langle v, v \rangle=\| v \|^2$.) Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

If 
$$
u= \left \langle v,w \right \rangle v \text{ } - \left\|v\right\|^{2}w
$$
then
\begin{align}
\langle u, v \rangle 
&= \left \langle \left \langle v,w \right \rangle v \text{ } - \left\|v\right\|^{2}w, v \right\rangle \\
&= \left \langle \left \langle v,w \right \rangle v, v \right\rangle \text{ } - \left \langle \left\|v\right\|^{2}w, v \right\rangle \\
&= \left \langle v,w \right \rangle \left \langle v, v \right\rangle \text{ } - \left\|v\right\|^{2} \left \langle w, v \right\rangle \\
&= \left \langle v,w \right \rangle \left\|v\right\|^{2} \text{ } - \left\|v\right\|^{2} \left \langle w, v \right\rangle \\
&=0
\end{align}
which means $v \perp w$.